# Creating Random Strinngs in Ruby with at least one sepcial character, one digit, one upper-case, one lowercase with no characters repeated in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, ruby-on-rails-3, random

My task is to generate a random string with following parameters:

1. At least one Uppercase
2. At least one lower
3. At least one digit
4. No repeated chars/digits allowed ( e.g. aa not allowed, aba is allowed, Aa is allowed)

I'm able to generate a random string with 1,2,3 parameters but parameter 4 logic is missing.

```
inputChars = [('a'..'z'), ('A'..'Z'),(0..9)].map(&:to_a).flatten
string = (0...16).map { inputChars[rand(inputChars.length)] }.join
```

Comment: A naive solution would be to check if the new random character is already in the string, and if it is reject it and try again. Unless your generated string is very long, i would consider this approach reasonable enough and not fiddle with some clever selection logic.

Comment: A small thing: you can simplify the calculation of `inputChars`: `['a'..'z', 'A'..'Z', 0..9].flat_map(&:to_a)`, but better is `[*'a'..'z', *'A'..'Z', *0..9]`.

Comment: @user1934428, I think you may have misinterpreted the question. The same character may occur any number of times in the string provided it does not immediately follow or precede the same character.

Comment: I see. In this case, just trying to generate a random character until a different one is produced, is even less a problem.

Answer (score 0):

```rb
require 'set'

inputChars = [('a'..'z'), ('A'..'Z'),(0..9)].map(&:to_a).flatten

set_string = Set.new
loop do
  break if set_string.size == 16

  cr = inputChars[rand(inputChars.length)]
  set_string << cr
end

output = set_string.to_a.join
```

i just change your map operation to loop operation and add Set data structure to store the character from random inputChars operation. Using Set will not allow same character

Answer (score 0):

Let's begin by defining two constants.

```
CHARS_BY_TYPE = {
  lower: ('a'..'z').to_a.freeze,
  upper: ('A'..'Z').to_a.freeze,
  digit: ('0'..'9').to_a.freeze
}.freeze
```

```
ALL = (CHARS_BY_TYPE[:lower] + CHARS_BY_TYPE[:upper] + CHARS_BY_TYPE[:digit]).freeze
  #=> [["a", "b",..., "z", "A", "B",..., "Z", "0", "1",..., "9"]
```

---

I will initially build a string of a specified length by randomly selecting one character at a time from the array `ALL`, ensuring that no two consecutive characters are the same. There is no assurance, however, that the resulting string will contain at least one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter and one digit.

```
def append_random_char(last_char)
  loop do
    ch = ALL.sample
    break ch unless ch == last_char
  end
end
```

---

Our main method will begin as follows:

```
def random_string(str_len)
  raise ArgumentError if str_len < 3
  (str_len - 2).times.with_object('') { |_,s| s << append_random_char(s[-1]) }
  # ...
end
```

For example:

```
s = random_string(40)
  #=> "arN64kDw6ClzcNMj8WAkj1NJC2B5oFoRlcXl5S"
```

`str_len` is the required string length, `40` in the example. Observe that `s` contains `38` characters of which no two successive characters are equal. We will need to add `2` characters later. If the string contained no digits, for example, at least one of those two characters added (at a random location) will be a (randomly-selected) digit. If the string were shorter and contained, for example, digits only, the two characters added will be an uppercase letter and a lowercase letter.

---

Next we need to see if the string is lacking an uppercase letter, a lowercase letter and/or a digit. (It cannot be missing all three, as the string must contain at least three characters.)

```
require 'set'

def types_to_add(str)
  [:lower, :upper, :digit].select do |type|
    st = CHARS_BY_TYPE[type].to_set
    str.each_char.none? { |ch| st.include?(ch) }
  end
end
```

For the random string generated above we obtain:

```
types_to_add(s)
  #=> []
```

meaning that the string contains at least one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter and one digit. Try this:

```
types_to_add(s.gsub(/\d|[A-Z]/, '')
  #=> [:upper, :digit]
```

See [Enumerable#none?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-none-3F). `CHARS_BY_TYPE[type]` is converted to a set merely to speed look-ups.

---

Suppose now we need to insert an uppercase letter, lowercase letter or digit to satisfy the requirement that there is at least one of each in the string. Specifically, we wish to insert a randomly-drawn character (from `CHARS_BY_TYPE[:lower]`, `CHARS_BY_TYPE[:upper]` or `CHARS_BY_TYPE[:digit]`) at a random location in the string we are constructing, with the restriction that neither the preceding nor following character is the same character.

```
def insert_in_string(str, ch)
  i = loop do
    i = rand(str.size + 1)
    next if ch == str[i]
    break i if i.zero? || ch != str[i-1]
  end
  str.insert(i, ch)
end
```

For example, if we were to insert the character `'0'` into (a copy of) our string `s` (which is not needed):

```
insert_in_string(s.dup, '0')
  #=> "arN64kDw6ClzcN0Mj8WAkj1NJC2B5oFoRlcXl5S"      
s #=> "arN64kDw6ClzcNMj8WAkj1NJC2B5oFoRlcXl5S"
                     ^
```

This inserts the character `ch` before the character in `str` at index `i`. If `rand(str.size + 1)` returns `str.size` `ch` is inserted *after* the last character of `str`.

Following this operation the final step is to use the method `append_random_char` to build the string out to the desired length.

---

The completed main method is as follows.

```
def random_string(str_len)
  raise ArgumentError if str_len < 3
  s = (str_len - 2).times.with_object('') { |_,s| s << append_random_char(s[-1]) }
  types_to_add(s).each { |type| insert_in_string(s, CHARS_BY_TYPE[type].sample) }
  (str_len - s.size).times { s << append_random_char(s[-1]) }
  s
end
```

```
s = random_string(40)
  #=> "PtQrVFZWUYFwiwRy3ySfAy42G1NT98J6cMVMaWeT"
s.match?(/[a-z]/)
  #=> true
s.match?(/[A-Z]/)
  #=> true
s.match?(/\d/)
  #=> true
s.size
  #=> 40
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it (warning: Not tested. Just want to present the idea
for my algorithm). I first take a random number for the length of the resulting random string (the length will be between 4 and 16 characters). Then I determine
randomly, how many of them are upper case / lower case / digits, and based on
these decision, I generate the string, ensuring that I don't get any duplicates
in succession.

```
uchars=('A'..'Z').to_a
lchars=('a'..'z').to_a
dchars=('0'..'9').to_a
charmap = { u: uchars, l: lchars, d: dchars }
total_length=rand(13)+4  # Total length of string to be generated
total_u=rand(total_length-3)+1 # Total number of uchars to be generated
total_l=rand(total_length-total_u-2)+1 # Total number of lchars
total_d=total_length-total_u-total_l # Total number of digits
# Array of types to generate
chartypes=([:u]*total_u + [:l]*total_l + [:d]*total_d).shuffle
# chartypes is an array similar to [:u,:d,:d,:l,:u], where the 
# symbols designate the kind of character to be generated.
# outstr : random string to be generated
outstr = charmap[chartypes.first].sample
last_char = outstr.dup
total_length.times do |index|
  loop do
    nextchar = charmap[chartypes[index]].sample
    if nextchar != last_char
      outstr << nextchar
      last_char = nextchar
      break
    end
  end
end
```